# Max AD/AP from items

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to try Fiora with max AD, and Katarina, Akali, and Syndra with max AP.

What items can I buy, including boots, that will give me the maximum amount of AD? What about for AP?

Comment: wait, are you asking for just the flat ap/ad items or item set that you can actually use in-game?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer by only paying attention to the title:

**Snowballing** AP/AD items:

- **Sword of the Occult** with 20 stacks grants 110 AD.
- **Mejai's Soulstealer** with 20 stacks grants 180 AP

---

**Mana influenced** AP/AD items:

- Manamune / Muramana
- Archangel's Staff / Seraph's Embrace

---

**Conditional** AD items:

- Maw of Malmortius (60-95 AD)

---

Flat (80 AD) items:

- The Bloodthister
- Infinity Edge
- Mercurial Scimitar
- Essence Reaver

---

Flat (120 AP) items:

- Rabadon's Deathcap
- Zhonya's Hourglass
- Deathfire Grasp

Comment: you can also add the 'Maw of someone' for ad. for ap users, they can also purchase 'Archangel staff for additional ap, provided you have good mana and have a mana reserve to begin with.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the AP % bonus on Deathcap.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question but as people have said before me its very open ended. I mean asuming you get alot of kills as ap you'd want to get some combination of Mejai's with rabadons, deathfire, and zhontyas. If you didnt you could literally stack rabadons for maximum flat damage output (the passive wont stack but ap will). Basically the items Fabian named are the right ones for "max damage" but you have to pick your combo.